# selecting input-field via placeholder - Element is not visible

Tags: java, selenium

Having a hard time entering text into the credentials page on:
[Pixiv](https://accounts.pixiv.net/login)

```
<div class="input-field-group">
<div class="input-field">
<input placeholder="E-mail address / pixiv ID" autocapitalize="off" value="" type="text">
</div>
<div class="input-field">
<input placeholder="Password" autocapitalize="off" value="" type="password">                                                
</div>
</div>
```

I am selecting the field using the following code as id attribute is not available:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Password']"));
```

but I am unable to manipulate the element via sendKeys nor clear.
it throws the following exceptions respectively:

```
 org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not visible
 org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually two elements on this page that use that XPath. The webdriver will choose the first element that meets the requirements set by the developer. Unfortunately the element you want is the second element in the DOM. However updating your XPath to be more specific will help:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='container-login']//input[@placeholder='Password']"));
```